# React Datepicker, exclude times of a date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-datepicker, react-dates

Im using this library:

https://reactdatepicker.com/

There are two props, excludeDates y excludeTimes, if i send, respectively dates or times, this exclude respectively too.

The ask if for exclude, by example 17:00 in 10 of december, and when i select 11 of december, 17:00 are enabled again

Here its a example how the times works, but excluding for all dates :(

```js
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dates"));
        var dataNew = new Date(data);
        console.log(dataNew);
        console.log("Hora:" + dataNew.getHours());
        console.log("Minutos:" + dataNew.getMinutes());
        var hourGet = dataNew.getHours();
        var minuteGet = dataNew.getMinutes();
        var c = new Date();
        c.setMinutes(minuteGet);
        c.setHours(hourGet);
        var excludeTimes = c;
        console.log("tiempos:" + excludeTimes);

        const isWeekday = (date) => {
            var b = new Date(date);
            const day = b.getDay(date);
            return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
        }

        var minTime = new Date();
        minTime.setMinutes(0);
        minTime.setHours(17);

        var maxTime = new Date();
        maxTime.setMinutes(30);
        maxTime.setHours(20);

        return (
                            <DatePicker
                                selected={this.state.startDate}
                                onChange={this.onClick}
                                filterDate={isWeekday}
                                placeholderText="Selecciona un día y hora"
                                showTimeSelect
                                minTime={minTime}
                                maxTime={maxTime}
                                dateFormat="MMMM d h:mm aa"
                                excludeTimes={[excludeTimes]}
                                inline
                            />
```